# android_app\app\src\main\java\ApiServices.java:49: error: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration @Query("artist_id") int artist_id

Tags: java, android, api, server

## ApiService.java

#### I'm relatively new to android.I'm trying to create a online music player app and i am not able to connect to the server api.

#### It gave me the above error and i don't know how to fix it. Here are my following code

```
package lrandomdev.com.online.mp3player.helpers;

import android.arch.persistence.room.Query;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import lrandomdev.com.online.mp3player.models.Album;
import lrandomdev.com.online.mp3player.models.Artist;
import lrandomdev.com.online.mp3player.models.Categories;
import lrandomdev.com.online.mp3player.models.Playlist;
import lrandomdev.com.online.mp3player.models.Track;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Streaming;
import retrofit2.http.Url;



public interface ApiServices {
    @GET("audios_api/audios")
    Call<ArrayList<Track>> getTracks(
            @Query("first") int first,
            @Query("offset") int offset,
            @Query("q") String query
    );

    @GET("audios_api/audios")
    Call<ArrayList<Track>> getTracks(
            @Query("first") int first,
            @Query("offset") int offset,
            @Query("categories_id") String categories_id,
            @Query("album_id") String album_id,
            @Query("artist_id") String artist_id,
            @Query("playlist_id") String playlist_id
    );

//    @GET("audios_api/album")
//    Call<Track> getAlbum(@Query("artist_id") int artist_id);

    @GET("audios_api/audios")
    Call<ArrayList<Track>> getPopularTracks(
            @Query("first") int first,
            @Query("offset") int offset,
            @Query("artist_id") int artist_id
    );
```

Comment: Did you solve a problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to use `retrofit2.http.Query` instead of `android.arch.persistence.room.Query`. Please try to change your import from: `import android.arch.persistence.room.Query;` to `import retrofit2.http.Query;`